# Is it possible to detach a tmux session by sending control sequences using expect?

Tags: expect, tmux

Consider the following `expect` script:

```
spawn bash
expect " \$"
send "tmux\r"
expect " \$"
send "echo hello\r"
send "\x02"
send "d"
interact
```

I expect this script to create a tmux session, execute "echo hello", and then detach.
The first two parts work great, but instead of detaching, I just get the literal characters `^Bd` on my terminal.

Is it possible for `expect` to send the `Control-B, d` sequence to tmux exactly like what happens if I type it on the keyboard?

Comment: Whoever made the close vote, I'm fairly sure `expect` and `tmux` are both covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) under "software tools commonly used by programmers;".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fiddled with this a bit, and empirical evidence suggests that the problem is with `tmux` rather than `expect`, but `expect` can work around it by adding a small delay.

In particular, it seems that if `expect` sends the sequence too quickly after the previous command terminated, `tmux` does not interpret the sequence and echos it instead. Curiously, `screen` does not have this problem.

```
spawn bash
expect " \$"
send "tmux\r"
expect " \$"
send "echo hello\r"

# Wait for prompt and then sleep a bit. Empirically, waiting for the prompt and not sleeping results in tmux not interpreting the control sequence some of the time.
expect " \$"
sleep 0.1

send "\x0b"
send "d"
interact
```

Comment: technically speaking `expect " \$"` is not correct. `expect " \$"` is the same as `expect " $"` which matches a SPACE char in the end of the buffer. you should write `expect " \\$"` or `expect { \$}`.

Comment: @sexpect-ExpectforShells, This is correct for my prompt because my prompt ends with a space, not a literal `$`.

Comment: It's not good practice to use only `" $"` to match a prompt in Expect scripts. `man expect` has this: "Note that in many editors, the `ˆ` and `$` match the beginning and end of lines respectively. However, because **expect is not line oriented**, these characters match the beginning and end of the data (as opposed to lines) **currently in the expect matching buffer**."

Comment: @pynexj It's a fair point, but my prompt changes with the working directory, and this solution sufficed for my purposes.